# How to call a function in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, iframe

I am making a WordPress website and I'm using a the **video theme**. I want when I create a new post I can place a URL link, the theme should place the URL in the iframe.

```
<iframe src='URL' width='620' height='350'></iframe>
```

I'm using the **detube** theme for wordpress which has some extra functions.

Comment: what function are you trying to call?

Comment: plz see my comments below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking for won't work in a theme, because theme code does not process the actual content of a post. What you're asking for is a plugin that will process post content to turn your URL's into iframes. This can be done with the `add_shortcode()` API in WordPress.

Here's an example plugin file you can drop into a new directory (like `video-shortcode` in `wp-content/plugins`. You can name the file `video.php`.

```
<?php
/*
* Plugin Name: Video ShortCode
* Description: A Video ShortCode
* Version: 1.0
* Author: Your Name
* Author URI: Your URL
*/

/*
 * To use this shortcode in a post, use [video]url[/video]. 
 *
 * Example: 
 *
 * [video]http://myvideos.com/vid-001.html[/video]
 */
function video_code($atts, $content = null) {
    return '<iframe src="' . esc_url($content) . '" width="620" height="350"></iframe>';
}
add_shortcode('video', 'video_code');
?>
```

Comment: thanks for supporting! this item works but want that i dont have to use short code i.e. i place url then it should be in iframes because some times i have to post 50-100 posts so writing shortcode will delay me! url is of only specific website (trolvid) i sont want to copy whole code !

Comment: my theme have some extra features http://snag.gy/cC0Xw.jpg you can see! pasted url in to be pasted in post it is pasted in the any field that can bee seen in pic.